# Monkeyrunner Opening Settings Programmatically

Tags: android-testing, monkeyrunner

I know MonkeyRunner is kind of deprecated, but I still have a weird question.
If I open Settings via touch events from Monkeyrunner **Users** option is not there,
If I do it as follows same thing.

```
FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK = 0x10000000
package = 'com.android.settings'
activity='.Settings'
runComponent = package + '/' + activity
device.startActivity(component=runComponent, flags=FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
```

Does anyone know why, or how to get Users to display or open using MonkeyRunner?
Running Android v6.0.1.
Thanks,
Eugene

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) to do it.
This is a `culebra` script slightly modified to check for **Users** while scrolling, but most of it is generated using [Culebra GUI](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/Culebra-GUI):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
'''
Copyright (C) 2013-2014  Diego Torres Milano
Created on 2016-01-11 by Culebra v11.0.8
                      __    __    __    __
                     /  \  /  \  /  \  /  \ 
____________________/  __\/  __\/  __\/  __\_____________________________
___________________/  /__/  /__/  /__/  /________________________________
                   | / \   / \   / \   / \   \___
                   |/   \_/   \_/   \_/   \    o \ 
                                           \_____/--<
@author: Diego Torres Milano
@author: Jennifer E. Swofford (ascii art snake)
'''


import re
import sys
import os


import unittest

from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient, CulebraTestCase

TAG = 'CULEBRA'


class CulebraTests(CulebraTestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.kwargs1 = {'ignoreversioncheck': False, 'verbose': False, 'ignoresecuredevice': False}
        cls.kwargs2 = {'forceviewserveruse': False, 'useuiautomatorhelper': False, 'ignoreuiautomatorkilled': True, 'autodump': False, 'startviewserver': True, 'compresseddump': True}
        cls.options = {'start-activity': None, 'concertina': False, 'device-art': None, 'use-jar': False, 'multi-device': False, 'unit-test-class': True, 'save-screenshot': None, 'use-dictionary': False, 'glare': False, 'dictionary-keys-from': 'id', 'scale': 0.5, 'find-views-with-content-description': True, 'window': -1, 'orientation-locked': None, 'save-view-screenshots': None, 'find-views-by-id': True, 'log-actions': False, 'use-regexps': False, 'null-back-end': False, 'auto-regexps': None, 'do-not-verify-screen-dump': True, 'verbose-comments': False, 'gui': True, 'find-views-with-text': True, 'prepend-to-sys-path': False, 'install-apk': None, 'drop-shadow': False, 'output': None, 'unit-test-method': None, 'interactive': False}
        cls.sleep = 5

    def setUp(self):
        super(CulebraTests, self).setUp()

    def tearDown(self):
        super(CulebraTests, self).tearDown()

    def preconditions(self):
        if not super(CulebraTests, self).preconditions():
            return False
        return True

    def testSomething(self):
        if not self.preconditions():
            self.fail('Preconditions failed')

        _s = CulebraTests.sleep
        _v = CulebraTests.verbose

        self.vc.dump(window=-1)
        self.vc.uiDevice.openQuickSettings()
        self.vc.sleep(_s)
        self.vc.dump(window=-1)
        self.vc.findViewWithContentDescriptionOrRaise(u'''Settings''').touch()
        self.vc.sleep(_s)
        self.vc.dump(window=-1)
        users  = None
        com_android_settings___id_dashboard = self.vc.findViewByIdOrRaise("com.android.settings:id/dashboard")
        com_android_settings___id_dashboard.uiScrollable.flingToBeginning()
        attempts = 10
        while attempts > 0:
            users = self.vc.findViewWithText(u'Users')
            if users:
                break
            com_android_settings___id_dashboard.uiScrollable.flingForward()
            self.vc.dump(window=-1)
            self.vc.sleep(_s)
            com_android_settings___id_dashboard = self.vc.findViewByIdOrRaise("com.android.settings:id/dashboard")
            attempts -= 1
        if not users:
            self.fail("Users not found")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    CulebraTests.main()
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this, but it seems as if opening settings via monkeyrunner is hidding the Users menu item, even using the drop down menu and clicking on the Profile icon then selecting More Settings, causes it to display a blank Users settings page. If I then manually to go to any settings item and back, then Users appear. I would just really like to know why or is it just my set-up?